# How do I set my rails 3 app to development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost

I need to set my rails 3 app on DreamHost to development mode.

In rails 2.3, I used to set it at environment.rb.
How and where do I do that for rails 3?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Ikahtz says, but:

```
# in config/environment.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your environment.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
```

Comment: I think you mean "development".

Comment: sorry, revised as suggested~~

Comment: You may want to revise that to a hard set. I bet DreamHost sets `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to `production` by default.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know setting your Rails environment via RAILS_ENV wouldn't help you on a DreamHost shared server because they are running their Passenger strictly with the production environment.