# Set environment to development in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I set my Rails environment to development?

According to this question: [How do I set my rails 3 app to development mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747891/how-do-i-set-my-rails-3-app-to-development-mode), you add `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'` to config/environment.rb.

I did this, but when I try to bundle install, it still tries to install gems for 'production'. I've placed the environment variable line at the start, middle, and end of file.

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Grafly::Application.initialize!

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. Bundler is a general-purpose dependency manager for Ruby. It has no idea that Rails exists. The `group` directives are exposing [Bundler's groups feature](http://bundler.io/groups.html), not a function of Rails.

If you don't instruct Bundler otherwise, it will install every gem from every group. It doesn't know what groups you do and don't want installed; it just knows that you defined some groups.

If you don't want to install all of your gems (or can't install all of your gems), you can skip production:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Similarly, you can skip development and testing gems when you deploy:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

(This is how, for example, Heroku and Cloud66 install only the gems you need for production.)